# Factorize ruby script based on Constant Array Loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Ruby on Rails 4 (ruby 2.2) app, i have inside a view:

```
<%= sanitize( @template.render(
                                    'text1' => modal['text1'],
                                    'text2' => modal['text2'],
                                    'text3' => modal['text3'],
                                    'text4' => modal['text4'],
                                    'image1' => modal['image1'],
                                    'image2' => modal['image2'],
                                    'image3' => modal['image3']
                                    goes on like this....
)
                                  ) %>
```

Where you see above 'goes on like this', it's because I woukd like to factorize this and use dirctly values coming from this constant:

```
MODAL_ELEMENTS =    [   "text1",
                        "text2",
                        "text3",
                        "text4",
                        "image1",
                        "image2",
                        "image3",
                        "video1",
                        "video2",
                        "video3",
                        "..."
                                ]
```

I want to find a way to change what's inside sanitize @template.render so that ruby loops through each of the MODAL_ELEMENTS items (text1, text2,..) and inject them like 'text1' => 'text1' => modal['text1'], 'text2' => modal['text1'] on the code above.

Today I have this but it fails:

```
 <%= sanitize( @template.render(
                  MODAL_ELEMENTS.each { |element| element => modal[ element ] ) ) %>
```

The difficulty also is that the loop has to add each coma (",") that we see here in bold:

'text1' => modal['text1']**,**

'text2' => modal['text2']**,**

...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just that string you want and that string is evaluated later then this code would do

```
MODAL_ELEMENTS.map{ |element| "'#{element}' => modal[ '#{element}' ]"}.join(", ")
```

Comment: Isn't there sme things missing like the closure of  the  } ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a hash named `modal` and `@template.render` also expects a hash:

```
MODAL_ELEMENTS.each_with_object({}){ |element, memo| memo[element] = modal[element] }
```

Using `#each`won't output anything. That array will be processed but won't return another array. If you're expecting it to return something you should use `#map`. That will return an array based on your input array.

With `#inject`or `#each_with_object` you can process an Enumerable and won't be limited to output an array. This example here will output a Hash.

Comment: thanks for your help. The thing is i don't want to output neither a hash or a array. As you see in the question, i just want to output: 'text1' => modal['text1'],
                                    'text2' => modal['text2'],
                                    'text3' => modal['text3'],
                                    'text4' => modal['text4'],.. there's no array nor hash

Comment: Oh.. You wanted to output a string. I guess @peter has the right answer, then.

Comment: interesting answre, it got me to look about performance between each_with_object vs inject vs each...http://engineering-blog.alphasights.com/tap-inject-and-each_with_object/#performance

Comment: how would you use inject btw? same way like each_with_object? i might be able to use a hash actually

Comment: In my opinion, `each_with_object` is easier and more intuitive. With inject you have to return the accumulator at each iteration. `MODAL_ELEMENTS.inject({}){ |memo, element| memo[element] = modal[element];memo }`

Comment: it's clearly more readable but it's strange that even if it has to return the accumultor at each iteration, it seems quite faster than each_with_object http://engineering-blog.alphasights.com/tap-inject-and-each_with_object/#performance. my use case needs to be very optimized ...